# How to prevent custom function execution when another function is executions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my situation:

I have a custom menu on right mouse click for my project. Here, I have `document.addEventListener` on click, that makes this menu invisible, like this:

```
var i = document.getElementById("menu").style;
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    i.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
        i.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 100);
}, false);
```

And it's great, works well, but I'm implementing a dropdown submenu that should be opened when you click on a certain element, like so:

```
 $('#change_color').click(function(){
      if($('#back_color').hasClass('back_color')){
           $('#back_color').removeClass('back_color')
      }else{
           $('#back_color').addClass('back_color')
      }
 })
```

The thing is that when I click on that `#change_color` then `addEventListener` is firing, which is obvious.

The question is – how can I prevent that listener function to execute when I click on `#change_color`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases using [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) and for simplicity in your code use [jQuery.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Code example:

```
$('#change_color').click(function (e) {
  $('#back_color').toggleClass('back_color');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @МаркЧолак Updated the answer according to your comment.. Thanks